# Facing issue in fetching data from database MySQL when requesting from different IP address

Tags: express, sequelize.js

I am using the Sequelize migration method for creating the tables and making the mysql connection.

Folder Structure is as follows:

```
root\
     src\
         api\
             components\
             controller\
             middleware\
             routes\
             service\
             app.js
         config\
             config.json
             global.config.js
         migrations\
         models\
         seeders\
         index.js
    .env
    .sequelizerc
    package.json
    package-lock.json
```

I am building an application based on express.js utilizing the sequelize for mysql and the app is listening on my PC's(Ubuntu) ip address. (I took IP address from setting -> network -> wired -> ipv4).

```
const server = createServer(app);
    
            server.listen(loadConfig.NODE_PORT, "192.168.0.xxx");
    
    
            //listening events and signal triggers
            server.on("listening", () => {
                logger.info(`server startup : PORT [${loadConfig.NODE_PORT}] : ENV [${loadConfig.NODE_ENV}]`);
            });
```

**Let's take a normal login api.
It takes username and password. In my local I am able to perform the login successfully.
With the same email and password when a 2nd person who is in the same network (192.168.0.abc) hits this login api then the api is getting executed perfectly in backend but 2nd person is getting the null data from the database.**

Here is the config.json file that was created automatically from sequelize migration.

```
{
  "development": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": "password",
    "database": "test_app",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql",
    "logging": false
  }
}
```

I am not getting why the 2nd user is not able to access the database data. He is receving the following the response

```
{"statusCode":401,"data":null,"success":false,"errors":[],"message":"Unauthorized"}
```

Comment: User privileges can be tied to specific host names. Looks like your root user here only has the necessary privileges assigned for the host name `127.0.0.1`, but not for `192.168.0.x`.

Comment: @CBroe ... I configured following configs in mysql.conf.d file ... filepath (/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d).

# If MySQL is running as a replication slave, this should be
# changed. Ref https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_tmpdir
# tmpdir  = /tmp
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address  = 0.0.0.0
mysqlx-bind-address = 0.0.0.0

I have configured 0.0.0.0
Is this what you are saying ? if I am not wrong.

Comment: 4401 is a http status code, it has nothing to do with mysql database. The database is connected from the node.js code running on the server.

Comment: @Shadow - Yeah but my pain point is accessing the data from database and not the response. It's but obvious if I am getting the null data then the response will be accordingly.

Comment: The IP address of the client is irrelevant from database access point of view as it is the node.js running on the server that will make the connection to the database. The database will not be aware of the IP address of the client using the API. You have not provided any error message either making it impossible for us to give you an answer. We can only guess.